# Current path based on voltage level

Tags: voltage, usb

I'm building a pet-project that involves a 'dumb' chinese USB PD IC (IP2721) and I'm trying to figure out if there is **an analog** solution for this problem:

Basically I have two circuits that require different voltages. Circuit A +9V and Circuit B +5V.

If voltage is 9V current flows to circuit A, but not B.
And
If voltage is 5V current flows to circuit B, but not A.

Comment: Do you consider a comparator to be an "analog" device?

Comment: Yes I do. Looked up on what it does exactly and seems like a potential solution.
So I guess I could use two comparators to drive two mosfets for different voltages. Or is there a way I could slim down this circuit by using only one comparator?

Comment: What are the expected current loads on the 5V and 9V circuits?

Comment: And what do you consider the threshold between these two voltages? 7V?

Comment: What happens when the open-circuit voltage from the power supply meets the "9V" criterion, but then the "9V" load drags the voltage down below the threshold?

Comment: @SolomonSlow That would indicate either a weak supply or a huge current draw. The OP has not specified whether either occurs, so I only added a short warning on this topic in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option among many. Arbitrarily decide that the threshold between the two supplies is 7V. Configure a comparator with inputs of a common 2.5V reference like the micropower, fixed LM4040; and a divider from 7V to 2.5V. If you designate the output of the comparator to be the 9V-active circuit, when it is low, U50 gate is activated and VL50 is high. Conversely when the 9V-active load is high, U50 will be disabled. Ensure that U1 is rail-to-rail.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feSprG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Another option that's less precise but also fairly simple:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWjy65.png)</sup>

That relies on knowledge of a stable Vgsth for your MOSFETs which may not be practical if you have tight specifications. Ideal FETs will produce something like this, with three regions:

[image: simulation]

In the first region, the gate voltage is insufficient to turn on either FET. In the second region (2.5-7V), the 5V circuit is active, and in the third region (7V+) the 9V circuit is active. If the supply is weak or the current draw is huge, you might see oscillatory behaviour where the 9V circuit load pulls the supply down below 7V, the circuit is disabled, the supply jumps back up and so on.

If you want to be more responsible and add some noise immunity, separate the 5V and 9V sections into two Schmitt triggers. The circuit I've shown below has hysteresis to:

- turn the 5V section on if the voltage decreases below 5.5V
- turn the 5V section off if the voltage increases above 6V
- turn the 9V section on if the voltage increases above 8V
- turn the 9V section off if the voltage decreases below 7V

These thresholds can be adjusted by modifying the resistors around the two op-amps. With the example op-amp, these are two halves of one 1A-out NCV0372.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg5xCA.png)</sup>

In simulation this produces, over one triangular cycle of the input voltage,

[image: hysteresis simulation]

Comment: In the first example: I asume I couldn't draw too much current from VL90 (comparator output).

Comment: Depends on the comparator used as well as your load.

Comment: Okay, so thats my fault there. I didn't specify the power requirements. but I guess ideally it would be better to drive a second mosfet to act as a switch for 9V circuit aswell.

Comment: It also depends on whether your load is OK with having an interrupted ground instead of an interrupted Vcc.

Comment: As to power draw, until you provide an actual number, anything is possible. There are power op-amps that support 1A+ (yes, one amp) like the On Semi 372 series.

Comment: I see. And their price doesn't seem to be much. Will investigate further. Thanks!